# How to give the word justification option to EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i know we can justify the words in TextView but is there any way to justify the words in EditText when the user is giving the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android not support it. But you can use this library for use:

https://github.com/programingjd/justified

Comment: @Akshaykumar Mark as solved if it help you solved that problem.